# Pipes.Concurrent: Sent signal is delivered one click later than expected

Tags: haskell, concurrency, gtk3, haskell-pipes

I'm using Pipes.Concurrent to write a short GUI program with GTK. It's a minesweeper-esque game, so I'm constructing a grid of buttons.

I construct and connect my buttons with:

```
b <- buttonNewWithLabel (show $ adjacencies board ! i)
on b buttonActivated 
     $ void . atomically $ send output (ClickSignal i (mines board ! i))
return b
```

And I connect the pipe with:

```
(output, input)  <- spawn (latest (ClickSignal 0 False))

let run = do
        sig <- await
        case sig of
            ClickSignal i isMine ->
                if isMine
                then do
                    lift $ labelSetText info (show i ++ " -- LOSE!")
                else do 
                    lift $ labelSetText info (show i ++ " -- Ok")
                    run
            Empty -> do
                lift $ labelSetText info "Empty Case"
                run

void . forkIO $ do 
    runEffect $ fromInput input >-> run
    performGC
```

It runs *almost* as expected. But if I click on button 1, nothing happens. But if I press button 23, it will update the info label to "1..". If I click on another button, it will update to "23..", and so forth.

I suspect that either I'm failing to understand how concurrent pipes are meant to work on some level or lazy IO is doing something weird.

Comment: Can you add a small, stripped-down, self-contained version of your code?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `latest` buffering strategy means there's always a value available to read in the buffer, so `await` will always return immediately; and `send` will likewise always succeed, so long as it gets a chance to run. A test program I wrote worked okay in ghci, but when compiled it never let the thread run that was trying to read from the console and `send`; I just got an endless stream of `0` until I terminated the program.

Your consumer `run` doesn't have anything in it that would cause it to pause, so it may similarly be starving the thread that is trying to `send` to `output`. If this is the case, a small `threadDelay 100` or so before each call to `run` might help.

Another possibility, and a more efficient one, would be to use a buffer that blocks the `Consumer` until there's a message to act on. To avoid blocking the event callback, you could use the `newest 1` buffer strategy, which would always succeed with `send` and overwrite the current value if there was already one there.

If neither of those help, then I suspect that there's something else going on with the way the GUI framework you're using is plumbed, but I am not very familiar with the GTK bindings in Haskell so I can't be of much help with that.